# Is it possible to fetch data on graph move, plotly js?

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I have thousands of different timestamp and value record and it is not possible to fetch all of them and show in the time series graph. Is there a way to fetch data when user move the graph to the left or right?

For example in first ss, I can see the data between 8:25 and 9:00, when I move graph to the right I want to fetch data again and see the data between 9:00 and 9:20. Is there any way to do it? I'm using plotly.js.

[image: ss1]

[image: ss2]